# Do not import configurations if already exists

Tags: 8, configuration

I have built a custom module and there are two configuration files in `config/install` directory of my module. When the module is installed the configurations are installed correctly.
When I uninstall the module and try to reinstall it, I get the error that that the `

> fields already exist in the database

These fields are defined in the configuration files and I want that they should be installed only if they not exist.

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move them to config/optional instead.

In that case, they will only be installed if they don't exist yet and if all their dependencies are met.